# NULL pointer comparison fails

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I'm initializing in a class a pointer to be NULL. Afterwards I check if it is NULL in the same class. But it's not always 0x0. Sometimes it's 0x8 or 0xfeffffff or 0x3f800000 or 0x80 or other strange stuff. In most case the pointer is 0x0 but sometimes it gets altered somehow.

I'm sure that I'm not changing it anywhere in my code. Is there a way it gets changed by "itself"?

Here's my code:

```
MeshObject::MeshObject()
{
    mesh.vertexColors = NULL;
}

MeshObject::MeshObject(const MeshObject &_copyFromMe)
{
    SimpleLog("vertexColors pointer: %p", _copyFromMe.mesh.vertexColors);
    if (_copyFromMe.mesh.vertexColors != NULL)
    {
        SimpleLog("vertexColors");
        this->mesh.vertexColors = new tColor4i[_copyFromMe.mesh.vertexCount];
        memcpy(this->mesh.vertexColors, _copyFromMe.mesh.vertexColors, _copyFromMe.mesh.vertexCount * sizeof(tColor4i) );
    }
}
```

My application crashes, because vertexColors wasn't initialized and is being copied. However it is NULL and shouldn't be copied.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't set the vertexColors in the copy constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This:

```
MeshObject::MeshObject(const MeshObject &_copyFromMe)
```

is a copy constructor. Because it is a constructor, it too should be setting the vertexColors member to some known & hopefully valid value, but it isn't, unless the value in the thing being copied is not NULL. But what if it is NULL? Basically, your if() needs an else.

Comment: It worked :)
It's a little bit strange - how does initializing the pointer in a copied class influenced the value in the class that is being copied?

What I mean is how setting this->mesh.vertexColors to NULL influenced the value of _copyFromMe.mesh.vertexColors being NULL or not NULL.

Comment: @Ilya To give a full explanation, we'd have to see how you were using the class, but I'd guess that copies are being made where you don't expect them to be. Also, if you have a copy constructor, you almost certainly need an assignment operator and  a destructor.

Comment: @Ilya: It doesn't influence it like that. What happens is that you copy your object more than once (implicitly or explicitly). First, you create an object with a garbage value in the pointer by copying, and then later you attempt to copy that "garbage" object as well.

Answer (score 6):

The code is incomplete, but there's one guess I can make.

When you construct an object of `MeshObject` class using the above *copy constructor* and the source object has `NULL` in its `mesh.vertexColors`, the new object's `mesh.vertexColors` will contain garbage because you don't initialize it at all.

For example

```
MeshObject a;
// `a.mesh.vertexColors` is NULL

MeshObject b = a;
// `b.mesh.vertexColors` is garbage
```

You need to initialize `mesh.vertexColors` in the copy constructor in all cases, not only when the source is not null.

Answer (score 3):

```
MeshObject o1;      // vertexColor is NULL
MeshObject o2(o1);  // vertexColor is undefined
MeshObject o3(o2);  // BOOM!
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, when your copy constructor is called, it does not call the normal constructor. The copy constructor must initialize the pointer to NULL in the same as the normal constructor. Else, it has a random value because you're using uninitialized memory. A decent compiler should be giving you a warning or error about this.

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback on what others have said, as a general rule I will initialize all members in a copy constructor that I initialzed in a non-copy constructor unless there is some compelling reason not to do so.  And I can't recall the last time there was such a reason.